# Missing file in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am having a problem with the GitLab CI. My pipeline is failing, due to a missing file.
I have this monorepository for my university programming assignments. The repository structure looks like this:

```
/                   ...the root of the repository
|-> hw_01/          ...the first assignment
|-> hw_02/          ...the second assignment
...
| -> Makefile       ...a global Makefile
```

In each of the assignments' directories, there is a `main.c`, `Makefile` and a bash `run.sh` script.

Also, in the root of the repository, there is an another `Makefile`. My pipeline is supposed to build the `main.c` for every assignment, and then test it.

So, here is how the process works:

1. the gitlab CI runs the root `Makefile`
2. that goes into every subdirectory like `hw_*`, and runs a `Makefile` there
3. that local `Makefile` first builds the `main.c`, and then runs a `run.sh` bash script, which is supposed to test the built `main` binary

However, for some weird reason, this does not work. It works for `hw_01`, `hw_02`, but then, all of a sudden, inside the third directory - `hw_03`, the pipeline fails with `./run.sh - no such file or directory`. As if the `run.sh` wasn't there. But I checked, and I am 100% certain it is there.

I have no Idea what I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[The complete CI pipeline output](https://pastebin.com/EqrP5cXG)

[The global Makefile](https://pastebin.com/CwHeKHm9)

[The local Makefile](https://pastebin.com/uemcQSJn)

PS: I checked that the `run.sh` file is really there, and I also put the two "build" and "test" stages together, because I wasn't sure if the "cleanup" stage that runs automatically after every stage is finished doesn't maybe delete some files.
I also tried putting just `echo "Hi, im here"` into the `run.sh` to make sure that the `no such file or directory` really is caused by the `run.sh`, not some code that is inside of `run.sh`.

Comment: the output of the ci indicates, that you leave the directory `hw_03` before trying to run the `run.sh`, which is why it is not found.

Comment: @JeanotZubler yeah.. but why? in the Makefile, it is clearly stated to first build, then run the run.sh, and then leave and continue to the next directory. So, am I to understand that the Makefile runs asynchronously or something? Because sometimes it gives the error, and then leaves the directory, and sometimes opposite..

Comment: Not an answer, but a few hints. Use pushd/popd rather than cd / cd ..; move the local makefile together with the global one and call it from the projet subdir with .. . In this way you are 100% sure there isn't a typo in one of the files